# Android: No Transition between Activities?

Tags: android, transition

Is there a way to have NO transition between Activities? In other words, no fade or slide out but an instantaneousness change. So for example if you have the same Button bar in Activity 1 and Activity 2 , it would look like that Button Bar never changed.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION).

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks! You know a way to stop transitions when press back?